# setAdapter "Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.widget.AbsListView#setAdapter"?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm calling the `setAdapter()` method in a class that extends `Fragment`. Note that I have imported `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` .

However I get an error stating that the API level is required to be level 11.

What do I have to do so that I can fix this without changing `minSdkVersion="8"` to `minSdkVersion="11"`

```
package foo.bar.qux;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TabFragmentList extends Fragment {

    String category, xml;
    NodeList nodes;
    int numResults;
    private ListView lv;
    Date date;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) return null;
        return (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.eventlist, container,
                false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (activity != null) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            ListContent[] item = new ListContent[3];
            category = (String) activity.getIntent().getExtras()
                    .get("category");
            xml = (String) activity.getIntent().getExtras().get("xml");
            TextView tv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.category);
            tv.setText(category);
            nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("event");
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                date = c.getTime();
                item[i] = new ListContent();
                item[i].setList(nodes, category, date);
            }
            EventListAdapter adapter = new EventListAdapter(activity,
                    R.layout.eventlist_row, item);
            lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter); // ERROR SHOWN HERE
        }
    }
}
```

Note : I tried reducing the targetSdkVersion to 10. Yet I get the error. Please help!

Edit : I don't understand why it's termed as `AbsListVew` when all that I have used is  a `ListView`.  Also, note that I've used a custom adapter.

`EventListAdapter` extends `ArrayAdaptere<ListContent>` and shows NO ERROR.

For your reference here is the xml layout code snippet for R.id.ListView1

```
<ListView
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: Make sure you're extending support fragment... just remove the import and change it

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`Right click on the project folder > Android tools > Clear Link Markers`

"Run Android Lint" makes some markers and the markers cause this error.

Comment: And I had to uncheck "When saving files, check for errors" under Preferences > Android > Lint Error Checking.

Answer (score 7):

Solution is just casting type to correct subtype as later Android versions introduced method call with same name.

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })

EventListAdapter adapter = new EventListAdapter(activity, R.layout.eventlist_row, item);
lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
((AdapterView)lv).setAdapter(adapter); //ERROR SOLVED HERE
```

Comment: I don't see a crash, explain, your comment is not useful otherwise...  You are casting to pre API 11 AdapterView so what you do here don't have anything with newer API , you are just telling compiler to use right method that exist in pre API 11 ...

Comment: sorry, I tested your solution and I had a "abstract method not implemented error". I have however found a workaround for my problem. in hindsight the solution might have work, it was my implementation that was not well executed. I will delete my response later since it was not relevent

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the docs [`setAdapter()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setAdapter%28android.widget.ListAdapter%29) method on `AbsListView` is available just from API Level 11. So there isn't much you can do, you can just cast eventually your `AbsListView` to a `ListView` or `GridView` and then call `setAdapter()`.

Comment: I've used only a `ListView` in my code. Just that I customized my `Adapter`. Where is the error then?

Comment: @Ovidu : I've posted the code. Could you please check and tell me now? Thanks:)

Comment: Can you also post the xml snippet where R.id.listView1 is declared? Maybe it's declared as an AbsListView there?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the "abstract method not implemented error" by casting my setAdapter method like this:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public void setAdapterSDK8(Adapter adapter) {
    ((AdapterView) this).setAdapter(adapter);
    ((StaggeredGridView) this).setAdapter((ListAdapter) adapter);
 }
```

This is related to the etsy staggered gridview